# Dynamically updating the vector and making it persistant

Tags: c++, vector

I am reading the content from user and getting each word with it occurrence value in vector array.

Each time program run vector get new content from user to process. Here in below example I have taken string statically.

I want

1. The set of words added in to vector to be persistent. I mean when in second iteration when user input new content; the new words with it's count values should be merged with previous vector value. And each time it would keep growing. Obviously as the scope of vector is main function so it get flushed each time program run. Can someone suggest me idea so that I can dynamically add the content in vector and make it persistent?
2. Previous vector content has word "mobile" with count value 5. And user content also has "mobile" with count 3. Then final vector should have word "mobile" with count 8.
3. Is there any c++ class or method which sort the content of vector alphabetically?

l

```
int main()
{
    typedef std::unordered_map < std::string, int >occurrences;
    occurrences s1;
    std::string s = "one two two three one one two";
    std::string input = "one,two; three";
    std::istringstream iss(std::move(s));
    std::vector < std::string > most;
    int max_count = 0;
    while (iss >> s) {
    int tmp = ++s1[s];
    if (tmp == max_count) {
        most.push_back(s);
    } else if (tmp > max_count) {
        max_count = tmp;
        most.clear();
        most.push_back(s);
    }
    }

    //Print each word with it's occurance

    //I want vector most to be declared and used in such a way that below coming value should remain persistent each time user perform action
    for (occurrences::const_iterator it = s1.cbegin(); it != s1.cend(); ++it)
    std::cout << it->first << " : " << it->second << std::endl;

    //Print the words with max occurance
    std::cout << std::endl << "Maximum Occurrences" << std::endl;
    for (std::vector < std::string >::const_iterator it = most.cbegin(); it != most.cend(); ++it)
    std::cout << *it << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first question is basically the usage of [serialization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serialization). In this case, the easiest option would likely be to just save what was in the vector into a file, and read that file back in when the program is next run.

For questions 2 and 3, use a `std::map` instead of a vector. This will keep everything in sorted order (based on a sorting criterion, which for strings is by default lexicographical). It also does not allow duplicate keys. For example, the following code would do basically what you want:

```
std::map<std::string, unsigned> words;
...
// Initialize mobile to have a count of 5
words["mobile"] = 5;
...
// Increment count when another "mobile" is seen.
++words["mobile"];
```

Comment: thanks, I have used `map` `typedef std::unordered_map < std::string, int >occurrences;` You meant should I replace `std::vector < std::string > most;` with `map`? And storing into file and reading back will become very expensive which I could not afford my requirement. can it be store in some datastructure like array or something ?

Comment: Well, you're going to need to store it in some kind of non-volatile memory or simply keep the program running. Any kind of in-program data storage will obviously be cleaned up as soon as the process exits.